# Help! Locked out of server after running `shutdown -h now`

Tags: server, ssh, shutdown, reboot

I've been locked out of server after running `shutdown -h now`. Now when I try to ssh into the server again, the error message is

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Jillian/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 159.203.165.140 [159.203.165.140] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 159.203.165.140 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 159.203.165.140 port 22: Operation timed out
```

How do I get back into the server?? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Get someone with physical access to the server to power it on.

Answer (score 5):

Press the power button on the server as "shutdown -h now" shutdown the server as in halt not reboot.  I think you where wanting "shutdown -r now"

Comment: Yes, definitely. I can't go back in time and change that though. Do you have an idea as to how to resolve the situation in its current state?

Comment: Get someone to reboot it for you. It's off. There's no other alternative.

Comment: Next time you can use the `reboot` command to avoid accidentally using the wrong parameter for `shutdown`.